# Allure report remove console output attachment?

Tags: nunit, allure

I have allure reporting setup for my c# selenium framework, and everything is working fine, but I have noticed something that bothers me that I'd like to change. In every single test, there is always an attachment called "console output" that is empty and 0kb in size. My question is, Is there any way to remove/disable this?

You can see what I mean in the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is the confluence of two minor bugs, one in nunit and one in allure.

On the NUnit side, the XML that is created for a test result contains an `<output>` element to hold the text output by the test. It sounds as if an empty element is produced when there is no output. You can check whether this is the case with your version of NUnit by examining the XML output.

On the allure side, an empty element could be ignored, but apparently, it isn't.

Either or both of these should be reported to the respective projects.